# How to get selected checkboxes from an array of checkboxes

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-fragments, checkbox

I would like to save checked checkboxes and get their string value.

What I am currently doing is using an array of checkboxes (about 20 cbs)

Declarations (outside `onCreateView`)

```
CheckBox checkboxNslWing, checkboxNsfDoor, checkboxNsrDoor, checkboxNsrQuarter, checkboxNsRoofRail, checkboxOsfWing, checkboxOsfDoor, checkboxOsrDoor, checkboxOsrQuarter, checkboxOsRoofRail, checkboxBonnet, checkboxRoof, checkboxTailgate, checkboxNsSill, checkboxOsSill, checkboxNsSlidingDoor, checkboxOsSlidingDoor, checkboxFrontBumper, checkboxBackBumper, checkboxMotorbikeTank;

private CheckBox[] allCheckBoxes;
```

Inside `onCreateView`

```
 

// Set Checkboxes properties
    
checkboxNslWing = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.NslWing);
checkboxNsfDoor = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.NsfDoor);
checkboxNsrDoor = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.NsrDoor);
checkboxNsrQuarter = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.NsrQuarter);
checkboxNsRoofRail = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.NsRoofRail);
checkboxOsfWing = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.OsfWing);
checkboxOsfDoor = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.OsfDoor);
checkboxOsrDoor = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.OsrDoor);
checkboxOsrQuarter = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.OsrQuarter);
checkboxOsRoofRail = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.OsRoofRail);
checkboxBonnet = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.Bonnet);
checkboxRoof = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.Roof);
checkboxTailgate = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.TailgateBoot);
checkboxNsSill = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.NsSill);
checkboxOsSill = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.OsSill);
checkboxNsSlidingDoor = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.NsSlidingDoor);
checkboxOsSlidingDoor = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.OsSlidingDoor);
checkboxFrontBumper = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.FrontBumper);
checkboxBackBumper = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.BackBumper);
checkboxMotorbikeTank = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.MotorbikeTank);

allCheckBoxes  = new CheckBox[] {checkboxNslWing, checkboxNsfDoor, checkboxNsrDoor, checkboxNsrQuarter, checkboxNsRoofRail, checkboxOsfWing, checkboxOsfDoor, checkboxOsrDoor, checkboxOsrQuarter, checkboxOsRoofRail, checkboxBonnet, checkboxRoof, checkboxTailgate, checkboxNsSill, checkboxOsSill, checkboxNsSlidingDoor, checkboxOsSlidingDoor, checkboxFrontBumper, checkboxBackBumper, checkboxMotorbikeTank};

        int cb = 0;
        CheckListener listener = new CheckListener();
        for (CheckBox box : allCheckBoxes) {
            box.setOnCheckedChangeListener(listener);
            box.setTag(1 << cb);
            cb++;

            if (box.isChecked())
            {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), box.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d("Operation", box.getText().toString());
            }
        }
```

`onCheckedChanged`

```
    class CheckListener implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            for (int i=0; i<=19; i++)
            {
                if (allCheckBoxes[i].isChecked())
                {
//                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), allCheckBoxes[i].getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.d("Operation", allCheckBoxes[i].getText().toString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The above works completely fine and I can see the logs which show the checkboxes being checked, my issue is below when trying to save the checkboxes in the database. Though it works it only saved the last checked checkbox and not any other checkboxes previously checked. E.g. if I check 1,2,3,4  it will only save the number 4.

```
else if ("Multiple".contentEquals(sel)) {
       
for (int i=0; i<=19; i++)
{
    if (allCheckBoxes[i].isChecked())
    {
      damage.setDescription(sel+" "+allCheckBoxes[i].getText().toString());
    }
}

}
```

Full method for saving into db

```
    public String saveDamage(String vehicleId, String damageId) {
        Damage damage = new Damage();
        Vehicle vehicle = new Vehicle();
        damage.setVehicleId(new Integer(vehicleId));
        if (damageId != null) {
            damage.setId(new Integer(damageId));
        }
        if (vehicleId != null) {
            vehicle.setId(new Integer(vehicleId));
        }

        String sel = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
        if ("Left".contentEquals(sel) || "Right".contentEquals(sel)) {

            String sel3 = spinner3.getSelectedItem().toString();
            damage.setDescription(sel+" "+sel3);
        }
        else if ("Front".contentEquals(sel)) {

            String sel2 = spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString();
            damage.setDescription(sel+" "+sel2);
        }
        else if ("Rear".contentEquals(sel)) {

            String sel4 = spinner4.getSelectedItem().toString();
            damage.setDescription(sel+" "+sel4);
        }
        else if ("Roof".contentEquals(sel)) {

            String sel5 = spinner5.getSelectedItem().toString();
            damage.setDescription(sel+" "+sel5);
        }
        else if ("Multiple".contentEquals(sel)) {

            for (int i=0; i<=19; i++)
            {
                if (allCheckBoxes[i].isChecked())
                {
                    damage.setDescription(sel+" "+allCheckBoxes[i].getText().toString());
                }
            }

        }

        damage.setNotes(txtEditNotes.getText().toString());

        try {
            damage.setCost(Double.valueOf(Objects.requireNonNull(txtEditCost.getText()).toString()));
        } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
            damage.setCost(0d);
        }

        String supCost = txtSupplementTotal.getText().toString().trim();
        supCost = supCost.replace("£", "");
        String supCostTotal = (String) (supCost);

        String deCost = txtDetailedEstimatorTotal.getText().toString().trim();
        deCost = deCost.replace("£", "");
        deCost = deCost.replace(",", "");
        String deCostTotal = (String) (deCost);

        damage.setSupplementTotal(Double.valueOf(supCostTotal));
        damage.setDetailedEstimatorTotal(Double.valueOf(deCostTotal));

        vehicle.setTotal(damage.getTotal());

        DamageRepository damageRepository = new DamageRepository(getActivity().getApplication());

        if (damageId != null) {
            damageRepository.update(damage);
            return damageId;
        }

        long insertId = 0;
        try {
            Future<Long> future = damageRepository.insert(damage);
            insertId = future.get();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Failed saving data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Failed saving data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return String.valueOf(insertId);
    }
```

Comment: Have a look at your loop: you keep overwriting the data set by the previous iteration, e.g. here: `damage.setDescription(sel+" "+allCheckBoxes[i].getText().toString());`. What do you think `damage.setDescription("sel 1"); damage.setDescription("sel 2");` would result in? I assume you want to _append_ the ids, so build your code accordingly.

Comment: Thank you @Thomas Each sel retrieves the string value from each spinner used, I've changed how its represented but the issue is not there.

Comment: The issue definitely is there. Think about how having multiple checkboxes and _one_ `damage` object should map. You need to either have multiple `damage` objects or _combine_ the ids of the checkboxes for the single `damage` you have.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it was easier then I thought.

I was overwriting the damage description in each iteration of the loop, that is was only the last one was saved.

Solution

```
    else if ("Multiple".contentEquals(sel)) {
                String d = sel;
                for (int i=0; i<=19; i++)
                {
                    if (allCheckBoxes[i].isChecked())
                    {
                        String sel5 = allCheckBoxes[i].getText().toString();
                        d += (" "+sel5);
                    }
                }
                damage.setDescription(d);
            }
```